# how to reply a special character value string using PHP without getting a blank value

Tags: php, string, replace

i'm having a problem with some code.
i'm having some kind of a chat bot that reply to the `$name` who chatted.

```
preg_match('%<b class="(.*)">(.*)</b>%U', $mess, $mem);
$name = $mem[2];

if (strpos($chat, 'alt="thanks"/>') != 0 && strpos($chat, 'Bot') != 0 || strpos($chat, 'alt="thanks"/>') != 0 && strpos($chat, 'Bot') != 0 || strpos($chat, 'alt="thank"/>') != 0 && strpos($chat, 'bot') != 0 || strpos($chat, 'alt="thank"/>') != 0 && strpos($chat, 'bot') != 0)

$mess1 = "[color=blue][big][b]@[/b][/big][/color] [color=blue][b]".$name."[/color] You Are Most welcome [/b]";

if ($bot_start==true) post_cbox($mess1);    

$log = fopen($chat_file,"w");

$data = $date.'-'.$chat.'|';

fwrite($log, $data);    

fclose($log);
```

my problem is that when the bot replies to the user `$name` if the `$name` has special characters it will reply blank name.
Example: $name =  or {name it will reply blank name as in only @(blank) without a name.
is there a way to edit this to work without using `str_replace` ?
since i already saw that someone fixed the code to reply the name even if it has special characters

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What the `preg_match` filter? and why?

Comment: @MeNa, the preg_match is to get the username from the chat table.

Comment: And this is the condition about returning name with special chars as blank?

Comment: @MeNa, yes, when a username `$name` start with `" ' < > { }` or any other code related character it will reply the name as blank and it will ignore the rest of message which in this case is `you are most welcome`
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Wont give you the special chars, but will fix something.

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
```

Comment: i'm trying to find a way without using replace functions
thanks

Comment: Are you using ISO codes for the special characters? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: the names are in UTF8 and i'm not a pro :)

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1) Put a regular expression on client side to prevent user using special chars (is easy to bypass, but you may don't care about security for some reason).

2) If the username is in regular place within the string, you can use `substr` [see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Or if there is a regular string right before the username, you can use `stripos` ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)) then `substr`.